# Select top 2 different foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

`PhoneBill` table

```
Id, Number,   PersonId, Bill
---------------------------
1,  123456789,  1001,    50
2,  123456789,  1001,    38
3,  123456789,  1002,    77
```

It's a Phone-Bill table, there are columns for phone number, the phone belonged to whom (PersonId), per-month charge (Bill).

I want to do a check if a certain phone belonged to more than 1 person. I know a way:

```
SELECT COUNT(PersonId) 
FROM PhoneBill 
WHERE Number = 'xxx' 
GROUP BY PersonId
```

But this is low performance, since it would look for all of the `PersonId`s. I just need to know if there are more than 1 person use this phone.

Comment: Think about..... the only way to know for sure that phone x only appears _once_ is to go through _every_ record regardless. These data algorithms are very old and very mature. SQL Server's plan optimisation is very old and very mature. There is no "quicker" way to do this, unless you want to save a count to the table at write time.

Comment: To put it another way, phone X might appear at the "start" of the search and might appear once at the "end" of the search. The only way to know this is to search everything. Likewise,  phone X might appear only once at the "start" of the search but the only way to know they only appear once is to search _every_ record.

Comment: As per below the answer very much depends on whether you are checking one (or a few) phone numbers, or whether you want a report for _all_ phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pl check this? Here you are not grouping first for all personid's so it needs less compute. Also, I am sure that postgres allows this syntax, but I am not sure about sql-server though.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PersonId)
FROM PhoneBill
WHERE Number = 'xxx'
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PersonId) > 1
```

Comment: There's nothing special about that query. It will run everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this with adding one more owner for the same number. It turns out `3`, seems also still look up for all.

Comment: The only way to know for sure if it is actually doing a "look up for all" is to check the query plan. (Noting the plan may change between executions). The `TOP 2` code mentioned so far is really the only code code that "implies" it should stop looking after it finds two. But again you need to check the query plan to be sure. Remember that the query planner is the thing that decides specifically how to service your query. You can't draw any conclusions about what will physically happen just from the query.

Comment: You reminded me of `DISTINCT`, and I figured it out a quite simple solution `SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 PersonId FROM PhoneBill WHERE Number = '123456789'`

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that the `GROUP BY` query would hve a significant performance impact, unless there were a very, very large number of rows for that `Number` value.

But you can also do this using `TOP (2) WITH TIES`, which will give you all tied results for the first two `PersonId` values.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasDuplicates
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (2) WITH TIES
      pb.Id
    FROM PhoneBill pb
    WHERE pb.Number = 'xxx'
    ORDER BY
      pb.Number,
      pb.PersonId
) pb;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 PersonId FROM PhoneBill WHERE Number = '123456789'
```

Stupid I was, that's quite a simple solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 2 Id 
FROM PhoneBill a LEFT JOIN PhoneBill b 
ON a.Number = b.Number AND a.PersonId != b.PersonId 
WHERE a.Number = 'xxx'
```

You can join the table itself on same number but different PersonId,
then check top 2 different ids.

Edit:

Considering Charlieface's suggestion, after some meditation, I think moving the condition `a.Number = 'xxx'` to JOIN ON clause could be better. Actually just need `TOP 1` to know there are different Person own a same phone.

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.Id, b.Id
FROM PhoneBill a LEFT JOIN PhoneBill b 
ON a.Number = b.Number AND a.PersonId != b.PersonId AND a.Number = 'xxx'
--WHERE a.Number = 'xxx'
```

Comment: Why do you think that's faster, it also doesn't give full results if there are more than one `Number` with multiple rows. If you just want to know about a single `Number` then you don't need the join at all, just do `SELECT TOP 2 WITH TIES ... FROM PhoneBill WHERE Number = ...`

Comment: @Charlieface, I did a little search for `WITH TIES`. Since we don't know how many rows for Person(`1001`), we can't be sure of the `TOP N`.